# Can Satan play with the words of the Quran to manipulate us?

Tags: quran, practical-islam, shaitan

I am going through problem, I cry a lot and all but only to Allah to seek His rehma.

I get these signs. Specifically, I have downloaded a Quranic app which automatically notifies me of verse of the day. Most of the time the verse explains my situation as if Allah is answering me.

Now my question is: Can it be Satan playing with me or is it truly Allah's guidance?

I am not a wali, I am a very sinful person.  Can it truly be Allah's guidance?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think we constantly say *اعوذ بالله من الشیطان الرجیم*?

And why do you think we say *بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم*?

We are instructed to start everything in the name of Allah:
Leaving the house, entering the house, entering your car, eating food, starting an exam, beginning a discussion,etc.

And I can tell that were Allah isn't, then Satan is there.

More important that physical matter it is the matter of guidance (*هدایه*). So basically if you want to be sure when you are reading Quran then always start with Auzubillah  & Bismillah, that will help.

Not starting with such means that you can take care of your own entirely and you don't need Allah's blessing... if you think such then it is when Satan can enter.

[*فَإِذَا قَرَأْتَ الْقُرْآنَ فَاسْتَعِذْ بِاللّهِ مِنَ الشَّيْطَانِ الرَّجِيمِ*](http://quran.com/16/98)

So when you recite the Qur'an, [first] seek refuge in Allah from Satan, the expelled [from His mercy].

Considering this: if you are a pious person and say such then Allah will bless and protect you insha'allah. But then if you are not pious and forget about the necessity of Allah's protection... and just read Quran with no cross-checking... and just interpreting as you wish then obviously Satan can and will try to deviate your understanding. Satan **can never alter our understanding**, although he invite us to *کبر* (arrogance) to be forgetful of Allah and to think we can understand Quran on our own and that itself is our downfall.

Comment: Jazak'Allah khair. Your words of assurance are very helpful in this time of need for me.. :)

Comment: Yeah, what @asma pointed out looks to be helpful remarks. especially the mentioned verse. Jazak Allah Khaira.

Answer (score -1):

Salam @n22,
IMHO you must be pleased as long as you are getting true guidance from Quran. Whatever is the source of the ayat in the app, you are getting correct message from the Holy Quran hence nothing to worry much. Still better, please join company of a good Sheikh whom you can consult regularly.

Wassalam,
Abdullah

Answer (score -1):

as i know, allah's direct guidance can be only in form of dream. if so, in your case it can be muslim jinns altering electrons in computer (maybe in its registers, memory's bytes, cpu cache, buses, etc) to help you.

as for the question in the heading: not, according to quran, allah saves quran's text from changing.